# UWP SQLite-PCL get queries are working very slow

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am writing Windows 10 Universal App (UWP). Simple functionality. I have local  SQLite database local file (.db) already full of records. So I basically just read from it and show information. The data file have few tables and junction tables, and the records are not so much, only 112 rows with 6 columns. This is my DataBaseConnector class:

```
 class DataBaseConnector
{
    public const string dbName = "HeroData.db";
    /*          connection element for SQLite universal platform            */
    //private static string dbFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "HeroData.db");
    Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock> connectionFactory =
            new Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>(
                () =>
                new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(
                    new SQLitePlatformWinRT(),
    new SQLiteConnectionString(dbName, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false)));


    private static DataBaseConnector db = new DataBaseConnector();

    private SQLiteAsyncConnection GetDbConnectionAsync()
    {
        var asyncConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(connectionFactory);

        return asyncConnection;
    }

    public static DataBaseConnector dbInstance
    {
        get {
            if ( db == null)
            {
                db = new DataBaseConnector();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }

   public static List<Hero> AllHeroesList = new List<Hero>();

    public DataBaseConnector()
    {

    }

    //Get All Heroes From DataBase
    public async Task<List<Hero>> getAllHeroes()
    {
        if (AllHeroesList.Count == 0) { 
         //< get records > 
        string query = @"SELECT hero.id, hero.name, hero.attack_id, hero.attribute_id, hero.role_id, attack.type AS type_name, attribute.name AS attribute_name FROM 
                        Heroes hero, AttackType attack, Attribute attribute Where hero.attack_id = attack.id AND
                        hero.attribute_id = attribute.id";

        var connection = this.GetDbConnectionAsync();

        AllHeroesList = await  connection.QueryAsync<Hero>(query);
        }
        return AllHeroesList;
    }
```

When I run it its working fine, but a little bit slow, ths method AllHeroesList(); took around ~1400 ms on Local Machine (Desktop) and ~300-400ms on Phone Device (Lumia 930 - Windows Mobile 10). I dont know why there is such difference in performance. I have more Get Methods, every one get info from database too slow. When I have to use 3 or more methods at same xaml Page 3x ~1400ms more than 4 seconds to show the content on Local Machine, on the phone device is quite faster ~1 sec. I want to increase the performance.

This is how I use the SQL methods in app pages:

```
   EnableProgressRing();

        if (ct != null && ct.Token.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            ct.Cancel();
        }

        ct = new CancellationTokenSource();

        heroRoles.Text = await Task.Run(() => GetHeroRoles(ChosenHero.id), ct.Token);

        IsWeakList.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() => DataBaseConnector.dbInstance.GetWeakAgainst(heroID), ct.Token);

        IsStrongList.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() => DataBaseConnector.dbInstance.GetStrongAgainst(heroID), ct.Token);

        DisableProgressRing();
```

I will be grateful if someone is able to help me with that problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the actual cause of your problem but you are creating a new `SQLiteAsyncConnection` with a new `SQLiteConnectionWithLock` with each query. Seems like a waste. Try creating it just once.

Comment: I tried, but the result is still the same. No performance improvement. :(